# Constant scrolling image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am after some functionality of part of a development site I am working on.

What I want to achieve is a set of 14 images, aligned horizontally, that constantly scroll horizontally so that they are showing 7 images at a time, and pause when you hover over the slider.

I tried using jQuery Cycle to try and get this functionality but I couldn't get the right parameters included.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have full control of the images or are they random/dynamic? For example, could you make one image (so it could be used as a background). Or what about the size, always fixed or dynamic?

Comment: Could you provide some code samples, a fiddle discribing the problem maybe?

Comment: Here's the link here - you can see the area that I mean on the home page just above the google maps with the 7 brand names. http://lincolnvideoproduction.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

Try this script. I have not used it but it seems to be what you are looking out for.

http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

Comment: It looks promising! Thanks, i'll let you know how it works out!

Comment: It works great - I would upvote but I don't have enough rep. Apologies